# How to send HTTP request to running docker container in Azure

Tags: rest, azure, docker

I got an Influxdb working locally. And with Postman I could send data to insert, select etc. 
I pushed it to my Container Registry in Azure and it's up and running 
`xxxx.azurecr.io/xxxx` is the adress.

Also it's running on port `8086`. With Powershell I can get into my container and insert data, modify and stuff like that. But what is the correct URL format to send data with Postman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Container Registry is used for storing and delivering container images, not for running them. You need another service for running the container. You can use these services in Azure for running:

- Azure Container Instance (ACI), https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-instances/
- Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS), https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/kubernetes-service/
- Web Apps for Containers, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/containers/

Comment: This solved it for me! Running ACI right now and it works like a charm =)

Comment: Thanks, good to hear! :-) I like ACI, too. It is an excellent service when working with containers. And there is a good path to AKS when your solution grows.